# Rails.cache.fetch not working when model given as key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I was under the impression that we could give Rails a model (anything responding to `to_param` or `cache_key`) to `Rails.cache.fetch` and it would create a key and cache the response of the block.

I have this code:

```
class ResultsPresenter
  def initialize(project)
    @project = project
  end

  def results
    results = Rails.cache.fetch("#{@project}/results") do
      sleep 3
      a = long_running_query
      b = another_long_query
      c = a + b
    end
  end
end


# called
project = Project.find(params[:project_id]_
presenter = ResultsPresenter.new(project)
presenter.results
```

`@project` was passed to `ResultsPresenter` and is an ActiveRecord model. When I specify `"#{@project.to_param}/results"` or `"#{@project.cache_key}/results"` everything works just fine. I also checked if the `@project` was being updated but it's not.

Anyone know why it does not take an ActiveRecord model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want your cache key to be an array, probably `Rails.cache.fetch([@project, 'results'])`.

This will give a cache key along the lines of `"project/5-20190812000000/results"`. The format for the model is `"model_name/model_id-updated_at"` with the rest of the array values joined with `/`.

If you were to look at the key generated from your example, it would look something like `"#<Project:0x007fbceaadbbc90>/results"`. This is happening because you are baking the value of `@project.to_s` into the value of the key you are passing into `fetch`.